# Python script to extract Django po file msgid strings

Tags: python, django

I want to write a Python script that would extract the msgid strings from the Django.po files generated by `makemessages` command for i18n.

Sample:

```
#: views.py:231
msgid "Jack and Jill went up the hill."
msgstr ""

#: views.py:34
msgid "Wrong choice. Select wisely."
msgstr ""

#: views.py:100 views.py:420 views.py:655 templates/thankYou.html:4
msgid "Thank You. You will be contacted shortly."
msgstr ""
```

I'd like to:

1. Extract each `msgid` string and place it in a text file.
2. Meanwhile, I'd also create a corresponding list of line numbers of the `msgid`'s `msgstr`s, so that after translation, I could easily insert the translated text back into their corresponding `msgstr ""` quotes
3. And then after I translate the text file wholly, I feed it back to the 2nd part of my script which then puts the translated strings back into their corresponding `msgstr` parts.

Any ideas how I should go about this ?

Comment: Why not translate the entries in the po file? It's format is stupid simple even for non-technical translators.